To Limit Laptop Lid Close Behavior before Login after Boot
BACKGROUND
I am trying to setup a 24x7 fully-on home server with my 10 year old MacbookPro laptop but I want it to be folded most of the time (due to physical space limitation).
While I do need to use the GUI occasionally so I would need a system with the GUI instead of installing the 'headless' server-version system.
So when the screen lid is closed (=laptop folded), I still need everything ON (including Wi-Fi and all the network services and apps running on the system) EXCEPT the screen (I want the Screen OFF only when the lid is closed)
CURRENT SITUATION
(1). Under GUI (after login) I changed the behavior of 'lid close' to 'lock screen', and disabled suspend (under my usual usernames as well as under root login). Now, after login under GUI, if I close the lid, the screen goes OFF (as I can tell from the APPLE logo light on the back of the screen) soon, with the network (Wi-Fi) being connected always (tested more than 10 hours).
(2). While with the settings mentioned in (1), if the system goes through a reboot (or fresh boot) without Login under GUI with the lid being closed, the system would connect to the Wi-Fi for a while and then being disconnected. And this is not what I wanted, because the system may be rebooted remotely without manual login under GUI.
WHAT I HAVED TRIED
(a)
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

(b)
In file /etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/nosuspend.conf

[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=no
AllowHibernation=no
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no
AllowHybridSleep=no

(c)
In file /etc/systemd/logind.conf

[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

(d)
In file /etc/systemd/logind.conf

[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=lock

Above (a), (b), (c), (d) were tried separately and a reboot was followed on. All of them could keep the system 'alive' (Wi-Fi being connected and services/apps running) BEFORE login through GUI. BUT under all the 4 situations, the screen keeps ON always (when the lid is closed)...
So how can I turn off the screen OFF (backlight OFF as well) only with everything else running even before login? Thanks!

To simplify the problem:
Boot-->Stays at the Login DM (I am using SLiM) without Login. If the lid is open, the Wi-Fi stays being connected; If I close the lid without login through GUI, the Wi-Fi would be disconnected soon (the screen goes OFF as well). With above (a) or (b) or (c) or (d) measure, the Wi-Fi stays being connected if I close the lid at the login DM (without login), but the screen also keeps ON always.

Providing some Ubuntu product & release details would be a start; especially if you're hoping for clear/specific details that will work on your release (rather than our own). Are you using the latest Ubuntu 24.10 Desktop? or something else?

One idea is to set your user to automatically login when the laptop starts/restart.

This may sound silly, but have you looked at the options for power management in your graphical environment settings options. Under XFCE the behaviour you want is configurable as far as I can see. KDE has similar options. Since I don't use gnome I am not sure about that, but there probably is something similar. I would think the same of aother desktop environments.
